# Pdf Text wrong character extraction

Tags: pdf, text-extraction, data-extraction

I have a [pdf page](http://www.mediafire.com/file/8q3vq9w3avu5h67/Tables.pdf) with a formula as:

[image: Formula]

When text is extracted, few characters are wrong. Text looks like this:

[image]

/ToUnicode Object 33 0 R unfiltered stream looks like this:

[image]

Encoding looks like this:

[image]

Rendering instructions are below:

[image]

Unicode Vulgar Fraction One Quarter (1/4) or 00bc seems to be rendered as Equals Sign (003d).

Is this information searchable in the pdf so that I can extract the proper character? Where is it located?

I've changed the question so it's not too broad.

Comment: @usr2564301 Yes, some of those other wrong characters are defined in other parts of the resources section.

Comment: @usr2564301 "Best look at its definition instead of the wrong one"... Please explain in more detail.

Comment: The original font itself which got stored in `/F6` is weird – definitely non-standard. All of its character definitions seem correctly decoded and stored as 1/4, Thorn, and eth characters. But the *design* of these characters makes them look like common `=`, `(` and `)`.  A character in another embedded font, the `&`, looks like a black square. There's nothing you can do about that; no meta information, no fix possible other than recognizing these fonts by their name.

Comment: *"Is this information searchable in the pdf so that I can extract the proper character? Where is it located?"* - Even inside the embedded font the glyph displayed as "=" is described as "¼". So it's just like @usr2564301 says unless you want to recognize the glyph drawing instructions drawing two parallel horizontal bars with rounded caps as "="...